# How to Open Login Screen Default in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using React Navigation 3 in that I used bottom tab navigator (main screen)  https://ibb.co/Jqzt37Y    it opens default .
But I want to add login screen which is open default (login screen Does not have bottom tab navigation)  when user click on login then open main screen .

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Code length is 500+ line ,my all main screen are complete i only add login screen in  other than bottom tab navigation

Comment: You can add your code by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case i would suggest to use a `switchNavigator`, that helps a lot in this cases.

A `switchNavigator` helps you exactly in this situation, making the navigation between his screens work like web pages, unmounting the latest screen as not needed anymore to keep it active. In your case it would become something like:

```
createSwitchNavigator({
    LoginScreen: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    },
    BottomTabNavigator: {
    screen: BottomTabNavigator . //where this would be your current createBottomTabNavigator
    }
})
```

When you are done with the login, you can just do a `this.props.navigation.navigate("BottomTabNavigator")` inside your LoginScreen

For more information you can reference to: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

Or write a comment if something is unclear